# How does NLP model know the output length during translation tasks?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

Translating English to French, we may have this:

Input: "Please help me translate this sentence"            6 tokens
Output: "Merci de m'aider à traduire cette phrase"         7 tokens

We have 7 tokens in the output. How does Bert model know this length during the network processing? Which hyperparameters are involved?

Comment: Bert is usually used to encode a sequence. Translating is usually done with a Seq2Seq model. Which model you are using? Otherwise, your question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence to sequence model (for translation) does not usually "know" the length of the output it predicts, but rather:

- encodes a full sentence to a (often fixed size) representation
- then, from said representation, predicts one output item at a time, until an "EOS" (end of sequence) item (token) is predicted, which marks the end of the prediction.

BERT specifically only does the first part, and creates a mathematical sentence representation from an input.